# MVC pattern and flexibility?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to the MVC pattern and as I go deeper in developping using this logic, I'm facing some issues which I can overcome, but I am not sure if I'm doing it the proper way (best practice).

So the issue:

I have a `View` that receives a `Model` that has the following structure:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    public List<MyItem> ListOne { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> ListTwo { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> ListThree { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> ListFour { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> ListFive { get; set; }
}
```

I want the `View` to show the first item from each `List` only when the list has records in it. So what I am trying to do on the `View` right now is something like this:

```
<div>
    @if(Model.ListOne != null)
    { 
        <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ListOne.First().Filename)" style="max-height: 800px;max-width:800px; padding-bottom: 5px;" />
    }
</div>
```

but when I run the code, I get an error stating `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`. So this means, as I understand it, that the View is first fully rendered and after that the code within is parsed and *converted* to the final HTML output (is this how it works? could use some clarification here also)

**So, what is the best way to accomplish this?** Do you loose flexibility when using MVC? Right now, it feels like it. This would be so much easier to accomplish when you had your code "mixed" with the HTML. Don't get me wrong, it is very clear to me the advantadges that using design patterns bring to a developer, but for this particular problem, it is really making me wonder about how flexible it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor *is* rendering this in a single pass from the point of view of your model, and you can freely mix code with HTML - that's what makes it so awesome!

The problem here seems to be the way you are trying to access the list.

Try changing this:

```
@if(Model.ListOne != null)
```

to this:

```
@if(Model.ListOne.Any())
```

At the moment you are only checking that Model.ListOne isn't `null` - i.e hasn't been initialised at some point in your model via `ListOne=new List<MyItem>()` or something similar - but what you *really* need to check is if `Model.ListOne` is *empty* or not.

I'd say that you should try to make sure as far as possible that you don't have `null` model properties when writing your view, it makes it very messy to have to mix in `null` checks; better to ensure that any model property you want to access in your view is intialised before you give the model to the view.

Comment: Makes total sense! The property wouldn't be null because I always initiallize it in the controller. I was not aware of the Any() method, thank you Stephen. Also thank you for clarifying how the code is rendered. If it enables me to have code mixed with HTML then I guess there flexibility is not compromised as much as I was thinking! Thanks once again!

Comment: Just my two cents on this. One should try to make the ViewModel as close to its consumption in the View. If the View is always going to display the first item from these lists, maybe you should revisit your ViewModel and just have single objects in them (rather than lists).

Comment: @Bazz yes totally agree - it's much cleaner to have the things you need in the view ready to go and keep the logix down to a minimum - would have pointed that out in the answer as well, but didn't want to muddy the waters!